# C++ program crashes after exit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I'm using the following function to open a dialog box, using the OPENFILENAME. Problem is, after opening the dialog box, and closing it, everything works fine, but when I exit my application then Windows says it crashed.

```
bool openDialog()
{
  OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
  char szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
  HWND hwnd = NULL;       // owner window
  HANDLE hf;              // file handle

  // Initialize OPENFILENAME
  ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
  ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
  ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
  ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
  //
  // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
  // use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
  //

  ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
  ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
  ofn.lpstrTitle = "Open File";
  ofn.lpstrFilter = "Custom File\0*.Cus\0";

  ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
  ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
  ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
  ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
  ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

  // Display the Open dialog box. 

  if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == true) 
  {
    path = ofn.lpstrFile;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I noticed it was the dialog box because the crash only happens if I use it at runtime, meaning that when I close the application without opening the dialog box at some point, it exits successfully.

Anyways, as far as I researched, it is probably caused my a 'heap corruption' or something similar that I don't have much knowledge of, so when my application tries to close, it doesn't release memory as it should (?). If anyone could figure out a solution it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: What I meant was have you actually tried to debug it?

Comment: It says the following. Windows has triggered a breakpoint in AnimationEditorTool.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in AnimationEditorTool.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while AnimationEditorTool.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Comment: I did try to debug it, it crashes and that window pops up everytime I the char array (szFile) tries to get deleted.

Comment: I love how the very first variable I mentally track isn't used. Reduce the program to a SSCCE

Comment: IIRC, there are more members in ofn struct than you are initializing?

Comment: I meant 'initializing' :)

Comment: Never mind - it seems that zero init. is fine and the other members are ignored anyway unless specific flags set.

Comment: Yeah, honestly I'm not 100% sure of the function, since I don't know much about the OPENFILENAME structure, I copied the whole algorithm for initializing it.
@sehe Sorry, I would reduce the code if I knew more or less where the problem is, but all I've figured out by now is that the problem is generated when I call that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is to do with `path` if this is simply a `const char *` or `char *` declared outside the function.

When the `openDialog` function returns, both the `ofn` structure of type `OPENFILENAME` and character array `szFile` go out of scope (along with all the other local, stack-allocated variables) and are no longer valid. As a result, the character array that `ofn.lpstrFile` and consequently `path` point to is no longer valid.

You should allocate space for the file name outside the function and perform a copy with `strcpy`, `strncpy` or equivalent before returning from it. Another approach would be to move the `szFile` character array out of the function and into the containing class as a member variable. Either way, the scope of the character array containing the file name returned needs to extend beyond the lifetime of the execution of the `openDialog` function.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your suggestions, but none worked. Although by doing so I came to confirm that it is indeed the szFile deletion that is causing problems (i tried using 'delete szFile;' and it crashed). I did what you said and moved the szFile to be a class variable, but still didn't work.

As I said earlier, the openDialog is working fine, it returns the path and closes alright, but it is when I exit the entire application (and specifically if I opened the dialog box at least once) that it crashes, I think now that it is probably because of the 'szFile' char deletion.

Comment: Simply declare `path` as `std::string` (or MFC `CString`) and be done

Comment: path is already a std::string. But I'm guessing i'll have to copy the 'ofn.lpstrFile;' value instead of equalizing it

Comment: Hmm. If you're already using `std::string`, assigning should be sufficient. I'm guessing there's something else going on. I think we need to see more of your program.

Comment: I forgot to mention something... And I think it was probably a huge mistake not mentioning it (sorry, my bad). That crash happens when I try to run the .exe generated (Visual C++ 2008), but not when I run it directly from the IDE

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about the lack of initialization of all the other members of ofn.

Comment: ..or maybe not - most seem to be ignored unless specific flags are set.